UWP App exception 0x80070057 "parameter invalid"
This one is driving me mental.
When my UWP app is executed in Visual Studio, either in Debug or Release mode, everything works fine. When I start it as a Release Build outside of VS, it crashes to desktop with this exception. It starts fine and then goes into what feels like "wait mode" or a stack overflow: unresponsive and then crash.
VS and UWP are at the latest version. Dev is a Win10 PC.
Again, launched in VS, this app works fine, no issues. Only outside it dies. AFAIK Error got introduced since the last update of VS.
Any help is greatly appreciated. I have tried to isolate the cause for two weeks now and am losing faith...
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBCD12BA99 (KernelBase.dll) in ApplicationFrameHost.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80070057 : 'Parameter is invalid.'.
onecoreuap\windows\dwm\dcomp\winrtnested\wrtvisual.cpp(1260)\dcomp.dll!00007FFBC8169CA0: (caller: 00007FFBC81A196F) ReturnHr(183) tid(2718) 80070057 Parameter is invalid.
onecoreuap\windows\dwm\dcomp\winrtnested\wrtvisual.cpp(1260)\dcomp.dll!00007FFBC8169CA0: (caller: 00007FFBC81A196F) ReturnHr(184) tid(2718) 80070057 Parameter is invalid.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBCD12BA99 (KernelBase.dll) in ApplicationFrameHost.exe: 0x80010012:

I want to know more details about your scenario. Would you like to tell me how do you install your app out of the VS? Is it sideloaded? Another thing is that what have you done after you launch your app? What is the logic in your app? If you are doing something when during the launch process. Have you tried to disable it and just show a new page to see if the behavior is related to your pervious logic?

Hi Roy, I'll break my answer in segments so it is easier to read:

I "Install" my app by building it in Release mode and then clicking on the Desktop icon to start it (all on the same PC). Worked like a charm before.

I have made no changes to the launch process since the last update of VS. The error has occured since then. There is lots going on during launch, none of which is the problem. It seems that launching a specific XAML page with data binding causes the issue. If I comment out a ListView, the page works. Detaching the ListView from an ItemsSource does not fix the issue.

This happens during startup. If I open a different page during startup, and then the "broken one", the page will load correctly.

I am doing several things in multiple threads during startup. None of those seem to interfere negatively.

This is a complex app that has taken three years to develop. Is there a way to trace where the fault occurs? I get the feeling it is during XAML rendering. If I make the ListView Collapsed, the page will render. If I show a naked ListView, it breaks. Is there a limit to the amount of ListViews on a XAML page in UWP? This is a desktop app level form with loads of moving parts...

Since you've already located the issue, could you please try to reproduce this in a blank project so we could take a look at that?

TT, will do. I'll post the results most probably later this week, traveling

Hope you've been well. Could you reproduce this in a blank app now?

Hi Roy, nope, that's not it. I am adding Content dialogs per line by line to home in.

It will be better if you could do this in a blank project which will be easier to find out the issue.

As I had indicated, No issues in a blank project

I am running a significant number of threads with IO tasks, that makes this bug finding mission so much fun. Issue only occurs when opening assets rapidly during startup. Opening them later does not produce the bug.

Based on your description, I'd suggest you add a delay before running these tasks since it could prevent the exception. You could make some tests to find out the minimize value of the delay.

You can try to isolate some components of your application, find out all things that could be launched on startup, then isolate/comment/disable all of them but not a testing part. While your blank project can be successfully launched on a desktop, I think may the problem be in some application code. And if the application will launch, go to test another part.

@Roy, the issue with that approach is the high dependency on the Win hardware platform. I am testing on an old Win10 laptop without SSD. That's the min req for my users. I will simply disable resume-after-sleep (opening the last document the user worked on) for the current release, that does not produce the error.

@Snail, that's what I have been doing for about 4 weeks now. Need to cut my losses and get this version out. The desired state is to launch into the last used artifact, but that produces the error. The app is -very- disk-based, I get the impression that the onslaught of OpenFileAsync chokes the sandbox, as UWP app sandboxes load a ton of DLLs as well as the app stuff. I agree, it's in the code. The grinding bit is that until the last update of VS2022, all worked fine. Something was changed in the way async IO is handled that breaks the code now.
